# Measures to quantify complexity of algebra equation

Tags: algebra

Like the title says, I am looking for ways to measure the complexity of an algebra equation.  For now, I am focused on linear equations, but I would think any metrics could be generalized for quadratic, etc.  I hoping the metrics can be useful for isolating student trouble spots and measuring progress in a rigorous way, as well as have a way to make progressively more complex equations to solve (this is specifically for U.S. Algebra I students).

Some examples to point out what I am looking for:

(1) $3x + 2 = 11$.  In this simple equation there are two operations, the moving the 2 over, and then dividing by 3.  I would think these operations would have different measures?

(2) $2(x+3)+1=13$.  Here there are two additional operations beyond (1), the distributive property and combining the numbers on the left.  Already (1) and (2) could contain 4 quantitative measures.

(3) $3-2(4-2x)=11$.  Here the working of negative signs add a different complexity.

(4) $2x+3(x+3) = 4x+10$.  Here there are $x$'s to combine, and an $x$ to move across the equals sign.

(5) $2x+1=6$.  I am distinguishing this from the 1st equation because the answer is a fraction.  Is this considered more complex?

So I am hoping there can be a set of scores that I can assign to an equation to determine complexity.  I've seen a lot of people talk implicitly about complexity, but I have not seen any explicit calling out of what makes equations complex.

Comment: I'm not sure this will be a well-defined measurement, as the distributive property need not be applied in (2). Do you want to measure some kind of minimum level of complexity?

Comment: I’m not looking for a well-defined axiomatic system. I am just trying to breakdown the complexity of algebra equations and map it to students’ strengths and weaknesses to see which features in algebra equations they can handle and which they struggle with.

Comment: For what it's worth, my experience in classes where students are learning (or even reviewing) how to solve such equations is that, on free response non-calculator tests (at least, after the widespread availability of calculators in the late 1970s), there is little difference between (1) and (5). For (1), students often go from $3x = 9$ to $x = \frac{9}{3}$ and then stop.